# If $x^2-k=0$ has only 1 solution in an integral domain $(R,+,\cdot )$ then $char(R)=2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I want to proof the above statement but I don’t really know how to do it. I already proofed that in an integral domain the above equation has at most 2 solutions, but I don’t know how to go on from there. Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: Is $k$ a fixed element of $R$?

Comment: It’s any element in R

Comment: State it this way: If there exists $k \ne 0$ so that $x^2-k=0$ has only one solution, then $\operatorname{char}(R) = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f$ is a solution, then so is $-f$. But if only *one* solution exists, you have $f=-f$. Since $k\not=0$ we must have $f\not=0$, therefore since $R$ is an integral domain you can cancel the $f$'s to get $1=-1$. What does this imply?

Comment: We haven’t defined roots yet

Comment: That was just notation. Fixed it.

Comment: But I think I got your idea. If for example $$k=1$$ then it must be $$1=-1$$ and this implies $$2 \cdot 1 = 0 $$ which means by definition $$char(R)=2$$

Comment: Yep the whole point is to try to show $1=-1$ so that $1+1=0$ thus the characteristic is $2$.

Comment: Thanks I will try

Comment: I think I have it but I don’t exactly see why $f$ can’t be zero?

Comment: If $f$ were zero then $f^2=0$ but since $f$ is a solution we have $f^2-k=0$ which gives $f^2=k$. But we assumed $k\not=0$ so this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much! :))

Comment: At which point do we use that R is an integral domain?

Comment: To cancel $f$ in the equation $f=-f$ to obtain $1=-1$, we use that $R$ is an integral domain. This is the cancellation property which says that if $ab=ac$ and $a\not=0$ then $b=c$. I changed the wording to make it hopefully more clear.

Comment: The cancellation property is actually equivalent to the statement that $R$ is an integral domain (has no zero divisors), see http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-cancellation-property-of-on-integral-domains

Comment: Now everything is perfectly clear to me!